# How To Completely Disable Android Keyboard

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-softkeyboard

I'm wondering if I can make some sort of Android application that runs a service which disables the phone keyboard over all applications, not just mine. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: If this is possible, it is a substantial security flaw. Hence, one hopes that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that your device should be rooted.